# Powershell: opening the cmd.exe and then running commands on cmd

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open the command prompt using powershell and then run an exe file with parameters.

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential $credential
```

Once cmd opens I want to run remotely an exe, e.g:

```
abc.exe -a arg1 -h arg2
```

How do I do the second part with Powershell, using the same credentials?

Comment: You can't. You'd need to pass `cmd` those commands as a parameter. E.g. by invoking `cmd /C abc.exe ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it as two separate steps; however, if you invoke `Start-Process` as

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList "/C abc.exe -a arg1 -h arg2"
```

you will accomplish what you appear to need.

Comment: my Arguments are actually " abc.exe -a applicationname -h hostname".. So will the cmd execute this abc.exe on the hostname passed as parameter?

Comment: If you started a command prompt normally, and typed `abc.exe -a appname -h hostname`, would it do that? `Start-Process` simply starts the process on the computer that the cmdlet is executed on; anything beyond that is the responsibility of the process being started. If you need to start the process on a different computer, you need to look into PowerShell remoting and/or WMI.